# How can I read a file constantly with AssetManager in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-assets

I working on a project. In order to take different inputs from a file, I need to read my file again and again (constantly). After my code reading the file once, while it running, I change it content but it can not see the new content. My code is here:

```js
Thread thread = new Thread() {

  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      try {


        AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
        InputStream input;

        try {

          input = assetManager.open("dummy_input.txt", 0);
          //RandomAccessFile in = new RandomAccessFile("file.txt", "r")
          Log.d(TAG, "here");

          int size = input.available();

          byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
          input.read(buffer);
          input.close();

          str = new String(buffer);

          //txtFileName.setText(text);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: handle exception
          e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Log.d(TAG, "local Thread sleeping");
        Log.d(TAG, "str3= " + str);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "local Thread error", e);
      }
    }
  }
};
thread.start();
```

Comment: How did you change contents of your app's assets while it is running?

Comment: I only changed "dummy_input.txt"  file in the assets folder

Comment: You 'tried' to change it. Well that is what you say. But you are not showing the used code. The code above only reads that file.

Comment: For my condition, is assets manager proper way ?

Comment: I change the "dummy_input.txt" file without code. I change it manually :) with notepad. I try to read dynamically

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR Whenever you change contents of assets folder, you should repackage and resend and reinstall your app to changes take effect.

Comment: The problem is, my code is not read the file dynamcally.

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR No, your codes read that file dynamically at run-time. What's it's problem?

Comment: @abforce .It is not good for me. Do you suggest me any other way for my situation ?

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR I cannot figure out your situation. Exactly tell me what would you like to get? How should your app act?

Comment: `After my code reading the file once, while it running, I change it content `. Sorry but this cannot be true as the file is read in a loop. And you are not telling how you change the file.

Comment: @abforce, It reads the file but I changed the txt file without repack the app. You say the main problem is this. Right ?

Comment: You changed the file with notepad on your pc. How can you think that it would have changed in your running app to on a different device?

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR Yes, Android cannot access your assets folder in your PC, It should be repackaged and reinstalled.

Comment: @abforce My app have to read a txt file dynamically it can contain only one digit "0" or "1" . If the txt file content is "1" then my app gives me a notificaiton.

Comment: @greenapps I connect my phone over adb to computer and then I changed the content

Comment: @HamzaGÜPÜR By ADB you cannot change a file. You can only fetch it out and then save it to the device.

Comment: @abforce yes that is my problem

Comment: You cannot grab and change with adb the content of a file in assets of your apk to begin wirh. So where are you talking about? And why did not you tell right away? All what you are doing makes no sense. If you want an updated file than update the file in the IDE. Then recompile, install and run.

Comment: @greenapps you are right. I am going to try another way.